# MySQL update a field with an incrementing variable

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'textile_events' in one of my databases.

```
mysql> describe textile_events;

+-------------+--------------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| token       | varchar(20)  |     | NULL    |                |
| reg_time    | datetime     |     | NULL    |                |
| eid         | varchar(20)  |     | NULL    |                |
| fname       | varchar(20)  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname       | varchar(20)  |     | NULL    |                |
| paid        | varchar(10)  |     | NULL    |                |
| seq_no      | int(11)      |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from textile_events;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     9325 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from textile_events where eid = 'headsup' ;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2553 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

'seq_no' field was introduced to the above table yesterday.

Now, I need to assign an incrementing number to 'seq_no' field for all 'headsup'
events where paid field is equal to 'paid'.

In other way, I am looking for something like this,

```
$i = 250
while( true ):
    $i++
    UPDATE textile_events SET 'seq_no' = $i 
        WHERE eid = 'headsup' AND paid = 'paid'
endwhile;
```

*How do I assign an incrementing number to a newly introduced field only to recods
that satify a given condition?*

**What are the available options and what is the most efficient way to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE textile_events e,
       (SELECT @n := 249) m
   SET e.seq_no = @n := @n + 1 
    WHERE e.eid = 'headsup' AND e.paid = 'paid'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59579c/1)**

Comment: Any clues how I could tweak this to prepend a string to the counter? E.g. instead of 1,2,3,4... foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4...

Comment: @kabadisha Just use `CONCAT()` like so `...SET e.seq_no = CONCAT('foo', @n := @n + 1)...`

Comment: Thanks! - obvious when you know how :-)
I was struggling understanding the syntax in the SET clause.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: attractive and simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Simple query would be, just set a variable to some number you want. Then update the column you need by incrementing 1 from that number.

Ex:: Query to update all the rows where a column is null. it'll update each row id by incrementing 1

```
    SET @a  = 50000835 ;  
    UPDATE `civicrm_contact` SET external_identifier = @a:=@a+1 
    WHERE external_identifier IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help you...

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS manual_increment_count$$
CREATE PROCEDURE manual_increment_count()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DSELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM textile_events;
    WHILE count > 0 DO
      SET count = count + 1;
      update textile_events 
        set seq_no = count  where eid = 'headsup' AND paid = 'paid'; 
    END WHILE;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL manual_increment_count();
```