# Increasing the value of a column until certain criteria meets

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with [this configuration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69c641/1/0)

I want to perform following operation:

let's assume a variable `amount = some_value`

```
for each row in ingridients_entry {
IF amount = 0
break;
END IF
IF amount > count - consumed
    SET amount = amount - (count-consumed) AND consumed = count
ELSE
    SET consumed = consumed + amount AND amount = 0
END IF
}
```

Is it possible with the sql UPDATE query?

I was thinking about using case with update in a procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE consumeIngridients(IN amount FLOAT, IN sr INT)
BEGIN
update ingridients_entry set consumed=CASE
WHEN amount = 0 THEN consumed
WHEN amount > (count - consumed) THEN SET amount = amount - (count - consumed); count
ELSE consumed + amount;SET amount = 0;
END CASE;
where serial=sr and count>consumed;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it is giving me error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET amount = amount - (count - consumed); count ELSE consumed + amount;SET amoun' at line 5

[View the schema here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEHKK.png)

Please help!

Comment: A `WHEN...THEN` statement returns a value, in this case the value that is set by `SET consumed=`. Do not use `SET` inside this statement. Also, do not have multiple expressions inside this statement (the ones separated by a semicolon--which by the way isn't your delimiter here since you set it to `$$`). Instead, let your `WHEN` statement return the value you want `consumed` to equal, and write the rest of your logic and assignments in an `IF` statement.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that!

Comment: Please edit your post to include your table layout, rather than a link to an outside site.  The link is broken, and even if it worked right now, it might go away in the future and would make your question useless to future readers.

Comment: Schema is provided in the form of image at the bottom of question: [View the schema here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hEHKK.png)

Comment: Just to be clear I want to execute those operation simultaneously, i.e., with every update exeution and IF statement doen't work inside update query. @Anton

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood your goal because I thought `amount` was a table field, and not a parameter. In your case, if you want to run an `UPDATE` query with some inline assignment and iteration logic, you can use user-defined variables. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html and an example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644551/mysql-update-a-field-with-an-incrementing-variable

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir @Anton for your kind help. Finally, I made it work, although it required some evil logic :P. `SET @amount = 4.5;
SET @debit = 0; 
update ingridients_entry set consumed=CASE
WHEN @debit>0 THEN consumed+(@amount := 0)+(@debit := 0)
WHEN @amount=0 THEN consumed
WHEN @amount>=(count-consumed) THEN (@amount := @amount-(count-consumed))*0+count
WHEN @amount<(count-consumed) THEN consumed+@amount+(@debit := 1)*0
END
where serial=1 and count>consumed;`